# Sleep by fraction of integer

Tags: go

I am trying to write a program that pauses for random intervals of time that are decimal numbers.

Here is the program that is not working:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

var test int

func main() {
    intervalGenerate()
}

func intervalGenerate() {
    var randint float64
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    randInterval := randFloats(3, 7, 1)
    randint = randInterval[0]
    duration := time.Duration(randint) * time.Second
    fmt.Println("Sleeping for", duration)
    time.Sleep(duration)
    fmt.Println("Resuming")
}

func randFloats(min, max float64, n int) []float64 {
    res := make([]float64, n)
    for i := range res {
        res[i] = min + rand.Float64()*(max-min)
    }
    return res
}
```

Currently a random number is generated between 3 and 7 (including decimals) but Sleep rounds to the nearest round number.

From what I understand the reason this is failing is because `Sleep` takes `Duration`, which is an `Int64`:

```
func Sleep(d Duration)
```

Is there a way to sleep a program for fractions of a second?

Go Playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/z-dnDBnUfxr

Comment: Just increase the precision before the integer conversion cuts off the fractional portion, e.g. `time.Duration(randint * 1000) * time.Millisecond`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use time.Millisecond, time.Microsecond, or time.Nanosecond depending on the level of granularity you need.

```
// sleep for 2.5 seconds
milliseconds := 2500
time.Sleep(time.Duration(milliseconds) * time.Millisecond)
```